# How come my HTML email code is not working properly on different widths?

Tags: html, email, debugging

I'm practicing writing HTML email code but for this particular issue, I've been stuck it on for a very long time no matter what I try.

When the view reaches <= 600px (when scrolling your screen to left), the `This text should be in the middle!` text is inside the `1200x1000` placeholder but not directly in the middle of it.

On the flip side, when the view reaches >= 601px, the `This text should be in the middle!` text is between the `320x30` placeholder and not inside `1200x1000` placeholder

Lastly, once it reaches <= 1207px, the left and right scrolling begins to happen on the entire page, which it shouldn't but not sure why it's happening.

I have no idea why these things are happening and just feeling like I've ran out of options in terms of fixing this.  What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?  A Fiddle is provided below as well: https://jsfiddle.net/s01mr3xp/50/

Here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900&amp;v=1.0&amp;song=cantbuymelove" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("https://use.typekit.net/anr2nbh.css");

        table td, table th {
            border-collapse:collapse;
            border-spacing:0px;
            mso-table-lspace:0pt;
            mso-table-rspace:0pt;
            border:0px none;
            padding:0;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
            .header-welcome {
                background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1200x1000');
                background-size: 320px 320px;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                width: 320px !important;
                height: 320px !important;
            }

            .width-320 {
                width: 320px !important;
            }

            .height-auto {
                height: auto !important;
            }

            .overload {
                display: block !important;
            }

            .hide {
                display: none !important;
            }

            .fontsize-11 {
                font-size: 11px !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <style type="text/css">
        .outlook-fallback {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;
        }
    </style>
    <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:AllowPNG />
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body width="100%" bgcolor="#f4f8f1">
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="width-320" style="margin: 0 auto;" width="1200">
                        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="width-320" align="center" ><a href="#"> <img class="width-320 height-auto" style="display: block;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/328x44" width="328" height="44" border="0" /> </a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="width-320" align="center" height="30"><img class="width-320" style="display: block;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x30" width="600" height="30" border="0" /></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="width-320 header-welcome" valign="top" align="center">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <font class="fontsize-11 outlook-fallback" style="font-family: museo-sans,Arial,Sans-Serif; font-weight: 100; font-size: 40px; color: #000000;">This text should be in the middle!</font>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img class="hide" style="display: block;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x1000" alt="Welcome!" border="0" />
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at these:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .header-welcome {
    background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1200x1000');
    background-size: 320px 320px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 320px !important;
    height: 320px !important;
  }

  .hide {
    display: none !important;
  }
```

```
<tr>
  <td class="width-320 header-welcome" valign="top" align="center">
    <a href="#">
      <font class="fontsize-11 outlook-fallback" style="font-family: museo-sans,Arial,Sans-Serif; font-weight: 100; font-size: 40px; color: #000000;">This text should be in the middle!</font>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="hide" style="display: block;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x1000" alt="Welcome!" border="0" />
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

When the screen width is <=600px:

- You are setting the background-image for .header-welcome class.
- You are hiding the additional image element `<img class="hide"`

When the screen width is >600px:

- The background-image is not set anymore
- The additional image element is shown and the text is placed on top of it.

Then, you have used `valign="top"` here:

```
<td class="width-320 header-welcome" valign="top" align="center">
```

Change it to `valign="middle"`. This places the text in the middle of the cell vertically.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realise it got put on hold.  Sorry about that.  Here's the answer:

At the moment every 3rd one is blue and every 5th is black.  I'm assuming you want the 3rd one after black to be blue.  You are going to want to change the css to

```
li:nth-child(5n-2) {
  background: blue;
}

li:nth-child(5n) {
  background: black;
}
```